# Reiterating through class vectors C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am still wrapping my head around classes and am still new to C++. My assignment is:

> Create three small classes unrelated by inheritance - classes
>   Building, Car and Bicycle.  Give each class some unique appropriate
>   attributes and behaviors that it does not  have in common with other
>   classes.
>
> Write an abstract class CarbonFootprint with only a pure virtual
>   getCarbonFootprint method.
>
> Have each of your classes inherit from that abstract class and
>   implement the getCarbonFootprint method to calculate an appropriate
>   carbon footprint for that class (check out a few websites that explain
>   how to calculate carbon footprints).
>
> Write an application that creates objects of each of the three
>   classes, places pointers to those objects in a vector of
>   CarbonFootprint pointers, then iterates through the vector,
>   polymorphically invoking each object's getCarbonFootprint method.
>
> For each object, print some identifying information and the object's
>   carbon footprint.

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to iterate through my `vector <CarbonFootPrint>`. I also do not know if the objects being created are actually being put into this vector. My code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CarbonFootPrint
{
    //class declarations
public:
    virtual double getCarbonFootPrint();
};

//class implementation
double CarbonFootPrint::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
    return 0;
}

class Building : CarbonFootPrint
{
    //class declarations
public:
    Building(double e = 0, int m = 12); //constructor
    ~Building(); //destructor
    double setElectric();
    virtual double getCarbonFootPrint();

private:
    double electric;
    int months;
};

//class implementation
Building::Building(double e, int m)
{
    electric = e;
    months = m;
}

Building::~Building()
{

}

double Building::setElectric()
{
    cout << "Enter your monthly electric in KWH: " << endl;
    cin >> electric;
    return electric;
}

double Building::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
     //I would like to print out the variable information for each object created
    //and then 
    cout << "The carbon footprint for this house is " << endl;
    //when it iterates through the vector.
    return(electric * months);
}


class Car : CarbonFootPrint
{
public:
    Car(double = 0, double = 0); //constructor
    ~Car(); //destructor
    double setYearlyMiles();
    double setAverageMPG();
    virtual double getCarbonFootPrint();

 private:
    double yearlyMiles, averageMPG;
    int co2 = 9;
 };

//class implementation
Car::Car(double ym, double mpg)
{
    yearlyMiles = ym;
    averageMPG = mpg;
}

Car::~Car()
{

}

double Car::setYearlyMiles()
{
    cout << "Enter in your yearly miles: " << endl;
    cin >> yearlyMiles;
    return yearlyMiles;
}

double Car::setAverageMPG()
{
    cout << "Enter in your average miles per gallon: " << endl;
    cin >> averageMPG;
    return averageMPG;
}

double Car::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
    //I would like to print out the variable information for each object created
    //and then 
    cout << "The carbon footprint for this car is " << endl;
    //when it iterates through the vector.
    return((yearlyMiles * averageMPG) * co2);
}

class Bicycle : CarbonFootPrint
{
public:
    Bicycle(double = 0, int = 34); //constructor
    ~Bicycle(); //destructor
    double setMiles(); 
    virtual double getCarbonFootPrint();

private:
    int calories;
    double miles;
};

//class implementation
Bicycle::Bicycle(double m, int c)
{
    miles = m;
    calories = c;
}

Bicycle::~Bicycle()
{

}

double Bicycle::setMiles()
{
    cout << "Enter in number of miles: " << endl; 
    cin >> miles;
    return miles;
}

double Bicycle::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
    //I would like to print out the variable information for each object created
    //and then 
    cout << "The carbon footprint for this bicycle is " << endl;
    //when it iterates through the vector.
    return (miles * calories);
}
```

Here is my main program:

```
int main()
{
    vector <CarbonFootPrint> *list;
    int answer, i;

    cout << "Welcome to the Carbon Footprint Calculator!\n" << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Main Menu\n" << endl;
        cout << "1: Set house info.\n" << endl;
        cout << "2: Set car info.\n" << endl;
        cout << "3: Set bicycle info.\n" << endl;
        cout << "4: Get carbon footprint for all items set.\n" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        switch (answer)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout << "\n" << endl;
                Building *anotherBuilding;
                anotherBuilding = new Building;
                anotherBuilding->setElectric();
                cout << "\n" << endl;

                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                cout << "\n" << endl;
                Car *anotherCar;
                anotherCar = new Car;
                anotherCar->setYearlyMiles();
                anotherCar->setAverageMPG();
                cout << "\n" << endl;

                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                cout << "\n" << endl;
                Bicycle *anotherbike;
                anotherbike = new Bicycle;
                anotherbike->setMiles();
                cout << "\n" << endl;

                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {

                //have it iterate through the vector and print out each carbon footprint.
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                cout << answer << " is not a valid option" << endl;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (answer != 4);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Take it one step at a time. There are too many problems here to deal with in one question.

Comment: You can iterate through a vector easily these days with `for (auto &footprint : list)`. Also, `list` should not be defined as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a crucial thing from:

> Write an application that creates objects of each of the three classes, places pointers to those objects in a vector of CarbonFootprint pointers, then iterates through the vector, polymorphically invoking each object's getCarbonFootprint method.

Instead of

```
vector <CarbonFootPrint> *list; // Pointer to a vector of CarbonFootPrint objects.
```

You need to use

```
vector <CarbonFootPrint*> list; // A vector of CarbonFootPrint pointers.
```

Instead of

```
{
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    Building *anotherBuilding;
    anotherBuilding = new Building;
    anotherBuilding->setElectric();
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    break;
}
```

Use

```
{
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    Building *anotherBuilding;
    anotherBuilding = new Building;
    anotherBuilding->setElectric();

    // Add the pointer to the list of pointers.
    list.push_back(anotherBuilding);
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    break;
}
```

Make similar changes to the other object types.

At the end, call `CarbonFootPrint()` on the objects:

```
for (auto item : list )
{
   item->CarbonFootPrint();
}
```

and delete the objects:

```
for (auto item : list )
{
   delete item;
}
```

Comment: so I changed it to read vector <CarbonFootPrint*> list; but when I changed my code to have list.push_back(anotherBuilding); it says error: conversion to inaccessible base class "CarbonFootPrint" is not allowed?

Comment: @JammarieClevette, and... what happened?

Comment: @JammarieClevette Remember what I said about too many problems for one question?

Comment: list.push_back(anotherBuilding); has an error. When I mouse over anotherBuilding it says conversion to inaccessible base class "CarbonFootPrint" is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your comments on R Sahu's post (I'm too new to be allowed to comment on other posts)

You cannot access the base class because it has defaulted to `private`,

```
class Building : CarbonFootPrint
class Car : CarbonFootPrint
class Bicycle : CarbonFootPrint
```

are all inheriting from `CarbonFootPrint` privately, which represents a "has-a" relationship, in this case although semantically a car has-a carbon foot print you're actually trying to make an "is-a" relationship, as these are all objects that implement the base class, possibly a better name for `CarbonFootPrint` could be `CarbonFootPrintProducer`.

The fix here is simply make them all publically inherited

```
class Name : public Base
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I remember seeing that somewhere and just forgot about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

R Sahu covered almost all of it, the only bit I see remaining is;

> Write an abstract class CarbonFootprint with only a pure virtual getCarbonFootprint method.

to which your class is not abstract as the function is not pure virtual, to do this simply add `= 0`

```
virtual double getCarbonFootPrint() = 0;
```

Pure virtual functions are ones that don't count as implemented, any class containing a pure virtual function is called "abstract" and cannot be instantiated. In this case it would have helped you identify your vector of `CarbonFootPrint` rather than `CarbonFootPrint*` to them, as the instantiations would be picked up by the compiler, although knowing template compiler errors you'd have had a couple hundred lines of error message for this simple mistake.

---

For full disclosure: a pure virtual function can actually be defined, e.g.;

```
virtual double getCarbonFootPrint() = 0;

double CarbonFootPrint::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
    // some code
    return 0;
}
```

which can then be called from any derived class

```
double Building::getCarbonFootPrint()
{
    return CarbonFootPrint::getCarbonFootPrint();
}
```

This is legal C++, allows you to define a default implementation, and still `CarbonFootprint` is an abstract class.

Comment: Just to clarify. You are saying I should change my code for class CarbonFootPrint to have virtual double getCarbonFootPrint() = 0 and then where I implement it I should put all of the different getCarbonFootPrint functions from my child classes into the base class? Then in my child class all I need to do is put return CarbonFootPrint::getCarbonFootPrint();

Comment: Nono, I was trying to explain in full the power of an abstract function. At present you're almost correct, just because your function is not pure virtual (=0) the class is not abstract, so you're not quite fulfilling the requirement. So my suggested change is simply to add =0 to your function in `CarbonFootPrint` so that you get all the marks in your assignment :)